# Heavily raining or Raining heavily?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Sentences :

> 1. It is/was heavily raining here.

Or

> 2. It is/was raining heavily here.

In a conversation with my friend I said that "Oh! Its heavily raining here".But he/she has corrected me as have to use "raining heavily" instead of "heavily raining".He/She  corrected  me to latter usage due to the common usages from  daily chats with the people.So which usage is correct or more correct and why ?

Comment: _Heavily raining_ is not idiomatic.

Comment: Your friend is [right](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heavily+raining%2C+raining+heavily&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheavily%20raining%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craining%20heavily%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: The only "reason" I can see for the obviously extreme usage preference in this *exact* case is "idiomatically established". But if anyone can come up with a more meaningful explanation, I'd want to see that any such reasoning or syntactic principles didn't force me to make a choice between *The temperature is **rising gradually*** and *...is **gradually rising*** (both of which sound fine to me).

Comment: Why the question closed and why it is off topic ? If so can I delete the question?

Comment: Please don't delete it. I personally can't give any better answer than @KateBunting's comment, but it's not obvious to me that justifies the question being closed. And it's always possible there's some other factor involved besides the "stochastic happenstance" of *only one version has become idiomatically established **for this exact context*** (I'd like to think there's some *reason* why ***gradually rising*** doesn't follow the same principle).

Comment: Suppose she said _We'll have to do some briskly walking, then_. Would you correct it (would she?) to _We'll have to do some walking briskly, then_? I would, and I agree with her original judgement, too, though none of these sentences are ungrammatical. And I don't know of any simple rule that will decide whether an adjective ending with _-ly_ should precede or fullow a noun ending in _-ing_.

Comment: It is the same idiom with "the sun is shining brightly" and non-weather events too: "The car was being driven slowly". If I heard "The car was being slowly driven" I might expect there to be more, such as "The car was being slowly driven into a field."

Comment: I find "do some walking briskly" to be slightly otiose. Anyway, just to be a contrarian (as someone recently said I was, [ha ha]), try this: **Heavily raining down insults on the assembled guests from the railing over the dance floor, Terry stomped out  somewhat unsteadily and fell flat on his face.** Yes or no, O language gods?

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is a difference between "It was raining heavily" and "The temperature was rising gradually". In the first case the subject of the verb is a dummy pronoun and in the second it is a normal noun. If we say "The rain was falling softly" we can invert the order to give "The rain was softly falling" and it works really well but we can't say "It was softly raining" with the same degree of comfort. I believe that the discomfort is related to the split infinitive which is acceptable when the subject is a normal noun but not, for some reason, when it is a dummy pronoun.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think your first example (_We'll have to do some briskly walking, then_) is ungrammatical. There, _walking_ is a noun, so I think it should be _some brisk walking_ instead of _some briskly walking_. I don't know how you can insert an adverb between a determiner and a noun.

Comment: @BoldBen Could you give me an example of the split infinitive being acceptable when the subject is a normal noun but not being acceptable when it is a dummy pronoun?

Comment: @BoldBen Also, "The rain was heavily falling" sounds to me as bad as "It was heavily raining". How about you?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I doubt the adverb _gradually_ is a typical manner adverb such as _heavily_. You can use it even as a clause adjunct as in _Gradually, the temperature is rising_ whereas you can't say *_Heavily, it's raining here_.

Comment: @JK2 I thought that "The rain was softly falling" and "It was softly raining" was an example of just that. I know that the structure is different but that's because "The rain was softly raining" doesn't make sense and neither does "It was softly falling" unless _it_ is a normal pronoun referring back to something defined previously. Also I agree that "heavily falling" is unacceptable in almost all contexts. This area of the language as it is spoken rather than the language as a set of grammatical rules is really complex.

Comment: @JK2: The issue seems to be that not all adverbs can be idiomatically used as *"**sentence adverbs**"*. Which I suppose is why *The rain was falling, **but it happened gradually*** is fine, whereas ***...but it happened heavily*** isn't valid (***heavily*** needs to be more tightly connected to the target verb ***falling***). I'm guessing the tightness of the required "coupling" also affects the idiomacy of putting the adverb ***before*** instead of ***after*** the verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed. But even CaGEL by H&P doesn't seem to recognize _gradually_ as a CLAUSE-ORIENTED ADJUNCT. That is, _gradually_ doesn't seem to be a DOMAIN ADJUNCT, a MODAL ADJUNCT, an EVALUATIVE ADJUNCT, a SPEECH-ACT RELATED ADJUNCT, or a CONNECTIVE ADJUNCT.

Comment: @JK2: I think once we're in the context of having half-a-dozen different "named subclasses" of "adjunct" to choose from, we're in the same murky territory as "numbered conditionals". Beloved of TEFL teachers and students, but largely irrelevant / unenlightening categories, from the perspective of native speakers who already know what they do and don't say even if they can't always assign useful labels to everything.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fair enough. BTW, do you think these two sentences mean exactly the same thing? _The temperature is gradually increasing_ vs _Gradually, the temperature is increasing_.

Comment: I can't really see much scope for those two phrasings (and indeed, *The temperature is increasing gradually*) to be assigned "different" meanings. Arguably the *second* term in *gradually increasing* and *increasing gradually* gets slightly more "emphasis" than the first (do we care more that it's *increasing*, or that the increase is *gradual*?), and some people *might* think that "fronting" ***Gradually*** as a "sentence adverb" gives that even more emphasis. But these are fine points of writing style that not everyone would recognise or agree on, so not really relevant here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly. And that's why it's hard to realize it can be a "sentence adverb".  In comparison, _Happily, they watched TV_ is clearly different from _They happily watched TV_ or _They watched TV happily_ in that in the first one, _Happily_ does not describe the manner of watching but only says that it's happy that they watched TV.

Comment: *They watched TV happily* = ***they*** were happy ***while*** they watched TV. *They watched TV, happily* (with a ***comma*** to create more "distance" between the adverb and the verb it's ***not*** intended to be coupled to, because it's a ***sentence*** adverb) = ***the speaker*** is happy with ***the fact that*** they watched TV.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm neither the OP nor the answerer, so I won't be notified of your comments unless you specifically direct them to me. Returning to the issue, you agree that _gradually_ differs from prototypical clause adverbs such as _happily_ in that the former still denotes a manner even when it's being used at the start of a clause, don't you?

Comment: I don’t think you’re going to get a good answer here unless someone addresses 1) the “weather *it*” — *It was raining heavily here* — which licenses the progressive-form weather verbs (*snowing*, *hailing*, *storming*, etc.) and 2) why *It was steadily raining here* sounds just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that fewer adverbs can precede the verb ***to rain***. When the adverb "describes" the way in which the rain falls or its quantity, it almost always follows the verb (even if it is a metaphor - see e.g. 3):

> - In the year 553 ***it rained violently*** in Scotland for five months. ([1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rained%20violently%2C%20violently%20rained&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crained%20violently%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cviolently%20rained%3B%2Cc0))
> - It ***rained steadily***, clouds resting upon the very treetops. ([2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rained%20steadily%2Csteadily%20rained&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crained%20steadily%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csteadily%20rained%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crained%20steadily%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csteadily%20rained%3B%2Cc0))
> - The blows ***rained thick*** on the chest of the prostrate man... ([3](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rained%20thick%2Cthickly%20rained%2C%20rained%20thickly&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crained%20thick%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthickly%20rained%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crained%20thickly%3B%2Cc0))

Short adverbs referring to the frequency of the rain are more commonly used before the verb:

> - Here are boundless plains where it ***seldom rains***, and you’ll maybe die of thirst ([4](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rains%20seldom%2C%20seldom%20rains&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crains%20seldom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseldom%20rains%3B%2Cc0))([inspirassion](https://inspirassion.com/en/adv/rain))

> - It ***rarely rains*** in Hollywood - and I love the rain. ([Danielle Campbell](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/danielle_campbell_997714))([5](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rains%20rarely%2Crarely%20rains&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crains%20rarely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crarely%20rains%3B%2Cc0))

However ***rain + frequently*** seems to be more common than the other option:

> - The air is on that account moist and unhealthy, and it ***rains very frequently***. ([6](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rains%20frequently%2Cfrequently%20rains&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crains%20frequently%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrequently%20rains%3B%2Cc0))

It was very interesting to find that this was the case with other "meteorological" verbs like *[snow](https://inspirassion.com/en/adv/snow)* ([heavily](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=snowed%20heavily%2Cheavily%20snowed&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csnowed%20heavily%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheavily%20snowed%3B%2Cc0)), *[blow](https://inspirassion.com/en/adv/blow)* ([heavily](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blew%20heavily%2Cheavily%20blew&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblew%20heavily%3B%2Cc0)).

Looking up ***heavily***, I found that it is almost always used [after active verbs](https://inspirassion.com/en/phrase/heavily). However, *heavily* always goes before the past participle of verbs in the passive voice, and before participial adjectives. See these examples from [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/heavily)

> - The compound is ***heavily guarded***. (passive - heavily + past participle)
> - She's ***heavily involved*** in the project. (passive - heavily + past participle)
> - Estimates of the amount of money needed to decontaminate the ***[heavily polluted](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=polluted%20heavily%2C%20heavily%20polluted&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpolluted%20heavily%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheavily%20polluted%3B%2Cc0)*** chemical installations vary. (heavily + participial adj)
> - The country ***depends heavily*** on foreign aid. (active verb + heavily)
> - It had ***snowed heavily*** during the night and in the morning the garden was a white fairyland. (active verb + heavily)

It may be that the "meteorological" factor might not play a big role in the position of adverbs, but there seems to be some kind of pattern. As for the use of "heavily" with verbs, we can also discern a pattern. It is only a pattern of use, I have not found any grammar rules that stipulate restrictions in the placing of this adverb before or after a verb.

Aside: I was also intrigued by the reverse situation of ***[gradually rising/rising gradually](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rising%20gradually%2Cgradually%20rising&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crising%20gradually%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgradually%20rising%3B%2Cc0)***. Yet I was fascinated to see that the Ngram discrepancy between the two variants diminished when I searched ***[gradually rise/rise gradually](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rise%20gradually%2C%20gradually%20rise&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crise%20gradually%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgradually%20rise%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crise%20gradually%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgradually%20rise%3B%2Cc0)*** (actually,"rise gradually" was  preferred for almost a century! It declined in favor to "gradually rise" only around 2010) or ***[gradually rose/rose gradually](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rose%20gradually%2Cgradually%20rose&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crose%20gradually%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgradually%20rose%3B%2Cc0)***. This does not occur in the case of ***heavily raining/rains/rained*** vs ***raining/rains/rained heavily***: the position of "heavily" after the verb "to rain" is uniformly and constantly more common throughout the last 3 centuries.

Addition: I found this example in the comments worth looking at:

> ***Heavily raining down*** *insults* on the assembled guests from the railing over the dance floor, Terry stomped out somewhat unsteadily and fell flat on his face.

Here, *heavily* precedes the verb, and this may be determined by the fact that  ***rain down*** is used transitively with the direct object ***insults***. I can't see how you can have ***heavily*** after the verb here:

> ****Raining down heavily insults*** on the assembled guests OR ***Raining down insults heavily*** on the assembled guests

looks clumsy. So, thanks to that comment, we've found another factor that influences the place of "heavily" in a sentence: the presence of a direct object.

Comment: Inserting _heavily_ between the transitive verb and its object may always be ungrammatical, but is it also ungrammatical to insert it after the object as in _Raining down insults heavily on the assembled guests_? I know you said it "looks clumsy", but the asterisk is normally used to indicate 'ungrammatical'.

Comment: @JK2 You are right, I will remove the asterisks.

Comment: But the first asterisk I think is okay, because _Raining down heavily insults_ is ungrammatical.

Comment: I am sorry :-), I must say I am not familiar with the implications of the asterisk. Is there a question on this site that explains it? I must look it up.

Comment: No big deal. All you have to know is that the asterisk is used to indicate an ungrammatical construction.

Comment: Compare to: The mercenaries heavily guarded the compound. She heavily involved herself in the project.

Comment: @fev The majority of your examples concern the simple present or past. They would be better as the continuous form, as per the OP.

Comment: @Greybeard Interesting point. Do you think it makes any difference in the word order?

Comment: @fev Possibly, as it gives one less position for the adverb and alters the form of the sentence. I've put my thoughts down on the specific matter in an answer. Your broader approach to the type of adverb and its position is well taken.

Comment: @MLVK Thank you for your appreciation. I am happy my poor attempt to find an answer was useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. It is/was heavily raining here. Or 2.   It is/was raining heavily here.

In the examples, it is important to keep the continuous form of the verb as the position of the adverb is semantically significant.

Consider:

3 *“The meal was quickly cooking.”* = the meal was cooking without delay / The meal was soon cooking.

This can also be expressed as

3a *“Quickly, the meal was cooking.”* / *"The meal, quickly, was cooking.”*

All the above are quite distinct from

4 *“The meal was cooking quickly”* = *"The meal was cooking at a rapid rate."*

In 3/3a, **quickly** is a free modifier – it modifies the entire clause. In 4, it is a bound modifier – it modifies only *cooking*.

In the same way, *It is/was raining heavily*, **heavily** is a bound modifier that modifies “raining”. And this is what is intended.

We can see that changing the position of the adverb in a sentence can often alter its meaning.

However, if “heavily” is used as a free modifier, its effect is that the meaning of the sentence becomes unclear.

That said, a search of Google Books for "heavily raining" shows a significant number of instances in Indian subcontinental English where a British or American speak might expect "raining heavily".

From ENGLISH for ELEGANCE and EXCELLENCE: for students of Higher Education  ...By S. Venkatesh

> 4. Since it is heavily raining I cannot go out now. (complex)
>
> I cannot go out now due to the heavy rain. (simple)
>
> I cannot go out now because it is heavily raining. (compound)

Comment: +1 for the regional aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Google ngram view](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heavily+raining%2C+raining+heavily&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheavily%20raining%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craining%20heavily%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cheavily%20raining%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craining%20heavily%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Heavily raining or raining heavily]

So that answers the question of which is ‘correct’ — by which I would mean, common usage.

Why? Usage, usage, usage.

Answer (score 0):

To put heavily before raining is to create a 'split infinitive' which is wrong. The adverb comes after the verb. It may sound alright as the famous Star Trek 'boldly go' but linguistically it's wrong.